# How to make a call to server using client private key and certificate provided by the server in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I'm new to ssl in java and need help.
My application needs to call a payment provider server with the certificates provided by them and my public key.

Things I've done:
1. created private and public key using openssl  and provided the public key to the service provider(server)
2. recieved certificate file(crt) from the server
3. created a jks file using keytool
4. added the certificate file to trust store
5. imported the keystore file to my spring boot application.

my code:

```
final String password = "password";
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
            .create()
            .loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("/home/workspace/gop/javaclient.jks"), password.toCharArray())
            .build();

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .build();

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory
            = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

    String url = "https://someurl.com/rndpoint"; // Web Service endpoint that requires SSL

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class);
    ResponseEntity<String> response2 = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class);

    System.out.println("Result = " + response.getBody());
    return response.getBody() + response2.getBody();
```

I have double checked and I have most certainly imported the certificate to cacerts.

My Output:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-19T08:28:18.871+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "I/O error on POST request for \"https://nabiltest.compassplus.com:8444/Exec\": 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to 
requested target",
    "path": "/nabil-payment"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve the problem. Here is my code snippet.

```
private RestTemplate getRestTemplateClientAuthentication()
 throws IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
 KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
final String allPassword = "123456";
 TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
 SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder
 .create()
//if you use keystore
 .loadKeyMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:keystore.jks"),
 allPassword.toCharArray(), allPassword.toCharArray())
//if you want to use truststore instead
//.loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:truststore.jks"), allPassword.toCharArray())
 .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy)
 .build();
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
 .setSSLContext(sslContext)
 .build();
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory =
 new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
return restTemplate;
}
```

now just call your endpoint using this function

```
// url ->  endpoint url
getRestTemplateClientAuthentication().exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class);
```